# ArgumentException: 'AddDbContext' was called with configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm working on a .NET CORE Razor project and getting the following error message:

```
ArgumentException: 'AddDbContext' was called with configuration, but the context type 'CarsDbContext' only declares a parameterless constructor. This means that the configuration passed to 'AddDbContext' will never be used. If configuration is passed to 'AddDbContext', then 'CarsDbContext' should declare a constructor that accepts a DbContextOptions<CarsDbContext> and must pass it to the base constructor for DbContext.
```

The project has no startup.cs file, everything is  in the program.cs file. I'm using VS 2022 .NET 6.

The code in the program.cs file is:

```
using CarsData;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<CarsDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbConn"));
});


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: The end of the exception message reads *"'CarsDbContext' should declare a constructor that accepts a DbContextOptions<CarsDbContext> and must pass it to the base constructor for DbContext"*. Start by doing what it says there.

Comment: so what in the code needs to be added or changed to make that work? A few things  I'm reading has what I have for  solution and still fails

Comment: The message tells you exactly that: *"'CarsDbConted ' ... a constructor that accepts a DbContextOptions<CarsDbContext>"*.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I'm doing code first and when I added this to the DbContext file, it was good to go:

```
public CarsDbContext(DbContextOptions<CarsDbContext> options) :  base(options) 
        {
            
        }
```